# Easy way to change .deb build prefix?

Tags: prefix, deb

I am trying to make a live CD for simplifying chrooting into unbootable Linux systems for users, as many unbootable Linux issues could be fixed with chroot, but many users probably don't understand the concept of chroot.

One of the abilities I want to add is the ability to temporarily import some utilities from the Live CD into the target system, so that they can be used as if they where installed, to do configuration tasks.

The problem is is that I can't seem to work around the apps trying to search for stuff in /usr/share when they are imported. (I already have a hacky workaround for /usr/lib using patchelf...) I would do a union mount on the /usr/share's, but that could confuse some package managers when they see files that should not be there, as the user might need to run a package manager to fix the broken system. (or at least I think it could confuse package managers).

I'm trying to see if I can create a script that will rebuild all packages to use a different build prefix instead of /usr. The script can rebuild packages with apt-get build-dep/apt-get source/debbuild, but it can't change the prefix.

**Question:** Is there a way to pass an argument to debuild or dpkg-buildpackage to change the build prefix?

Right now it seems I have to take a look at the contents of the source (from apt-get source) for every package and see what files are specifying /usr and figure out a way to change it for every one, but I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is feasible. Why don't you mount in a different location, for example /usr/local? That way, you also eliminate a source for possible conflicts.

Still, some packages are full of hardcoded references to the location for their data files, for example.

I'll throw in a pointer to `stow` as well, although I imagine it's not really helpful for your scenario.

Comment: I'm actually trying to get it to compile to something like /usr/local (it's a folder with a name in /usr that I made up so I don't conflict anything) Seeing that if it might be hardcoded, I'm trying to see if I can get away with using find and sed to replace all references to the usr folder to the folder that I want.

Comment: I know its hacky, but its not a permanent system to install, and I'm going to have to do it for every package.

Thanks for the tip, I just don't know why I didn't think of sed before
Thanks, and sorry about posting on the wrong site.